# Elastalert default install location

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastalert

I followed [this url](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html#downloading-and-configuring) to install Elastalert, however I don't even know where is that config.yaml.example file is located. Where does the elastalert gets installed by default? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/blob/master/config.yaml.example

If you installed via pip, this file does not get installed.

If you cloned the repo, it will be in the base directory.

Answer (score 2):

I installed via `pip` and was unable to locate the `config.yaml` file. So I uninstalled `elastalert` and cloned the repo and ran other steps as mentioned in the [documentation](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html)

In short these steps worked for me. If you have already installed it via `pip` then 
    `pip uninstall elastalert`

```
git clone https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert.git
pip install "setuptools>=11.3"
python setup.py install
```

for ES > 5.0.0

`pip install "elasticsearch>=5.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Well I am pretty sure that elastalert does not provide you with a filled in cofig file.

When you install it via pip i would suggest that you copy the example from git and fill it yourself. Then pass it on as a --config parameter when calling elastalert.

I know the thread is very old but I myself spent considerable amount of time at one point trying to get it to work and thought that I will leave it here.

Comment: This does not answer *Where does the elastalert [get] installed by default?*